# Twilio Studio - Make outgoing call make http request on hangup

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a Studio Flow where I want to send HTTP requests a lot between different steps in my flow.

At first, I trigger the flow with rest API and use "make outgoing call" widget to call the user. If anything else happens than the user picking up, I want to send a HTTP request to my server what happened.
I have created the first part of my flow to test these HTTP requests:
[image: twilio studio flow http requests]

Whatever I do except for picking up the phone, eg: letting it ring untill the end, immediately hanging up when i get called, making sure my line is busy when i get called, ... None of these events are being sent to my database.

I know the HTTP request widget and my URL to post to is working, because when I attach a HTTP request widget under "Answered", I am getting results in my database.

I have played around with the "TIMEOUT" option in the 'make outgoing call' widget. But I am unsure how to play around this. 
If I set it too low (ie: 10seconds), the phone will stop ringing after 10seconds (but the http requests will go through fine). If I set it too high (ie: 60seconds), my phone will have stopped the phone call after +- 20seconds by itself, and no http requests will have gone through.

How do I make sure I catch all actions that happen?

EDIT: An example of a log for a flow where the timeout is set to 60seconds.
[image: log hangup event flow]

Comment: That's weird. I'm not sure this is something we can fix on Stack Overflow. I'd recommend you send this information to [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) including some Execution Sids for executions of the flow where it didn't behave.